# Looking For Best Practices Way To Get Value From List of Grouped Radio Buttons With Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm putting together a presentation on using bootstrap with segmented radio buttons (multiple groups of them) and I want to show the best way to capture the value of not only the radio button value but also the group that it came from. I've put together a very simple example that works and also posted a fiddle of it.

Basically, I'm capturing the info in the radio buttons change event.  Will all my friends laugh at me because there is a much better way to do this with bootstrap?  All suggestions are welcome as I want to make sure I'm showing a very good way to do this in my presentation.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pkellner99/DTcHh/26735/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="all-sessions">
        <div class="btn-group professional-session" data-toggle="buttons" data-sessionid="101">
            <b>Session 101</b>
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                <input checked="checked" name="session-interest-101" type="radio" value="NoInterest" /> NoInterested
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input name="session-interest-101" type="radio" value="Interested" /> Interested
            </label>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="btn-group professional-session" data-toggle="buttons" data-sessionid="102">
            <b>Session 102</b>
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                <input checked="checked" name="session-interest-102" type="radio" value="NoInterest" /> NoInterested
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input name="session-interest-102" type="radio" value="Interested" /> Interested
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document)
            .ready(function () {
                $('input')
                    .change(function () {
                        console.log(' sessionId: ' + $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-sessionid'));
                        console.log(' val:       ' + $(this).val());
                    });
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you're confusing the functionality of the JS file supplied by bootstrap and jQuery. Using jQuery to retrieve the value of radio buttons work just as fine. In fact, Bootstrap.js is built on top of jQuery, and that's pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks @Terry   Is there a "bootstrap" way to do this?  I realize that what I've done has nothing to do with bootstrap but I would like to take advantage of what is in bootstrap if possible.  I don't know how to do that. Suggestion?

Comment: That has nothing to do with bootstrap. Bootstrap is used for presentation, and that's pretty much it. You're comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @Terry , doesn't bootstrap have a bunch of javascript built in that you can somehow get in on their event pipeline?  How would a bootstrap expert solve the problem of capturing the value of multiple groups of radio buttons (and POSTing that back to a service)

Comment: I think I'm losing you. Binding multiple event listeners to the same element would not cause them to override, so you wouldn't even interfere with the functionality of Bootstrap (unless you choose to unbind the event listeners). You're asking a little out of scope now with the second question. The trick is to use AJAX if you want to dynamically make GET/POST requests.

Comment: I think you @Terry are mis-understanding the intent of my question as this discussion is not out of scope.  I've seen modal popups in bootstrap that do not require any additional javascript and I believe they still work (obviously jquery is happening under the hood).  My question is asking if there is a better way to get the radiobutton values than simply ignoring bootstrap.